# Listing select option values with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following HTML code

```
<select name="countries" class_id="countries">
    <option value="-1">--SELECT COUNTRY--</option>
    <option value="459">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="100">USA</option>
    <option value="300">UK</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get a list of the option values (like 459, 100, etc, not the text) using Selenium.

At the moment I have the following Python code

```
from selenium import webdriver

def country_values(website_url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(website_url)
    html_code=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='countries']")[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
    return html_code
```

As you can see the code returns pure HTML, which I am parsing with HTMLParser library. Is there any way to get the option values just using Selenium? In other words, without having to parse the result from Selenium?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

check it out, here is how i did it before i knew what the Select Module did

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
#code to get you to the page

select_box = browser.find_element_by_name("countries") 
# if your select_box has a name.. why use xpath?..... 
# this step could use either xpath or name, but name is sooo much easier.

options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
# this part is cool, because it searches the elements contained inside of select_box 
# and then adds them to the list options if they have the tag name "options"

for element in options:
    print(element.get_attribute("value"))
    # or append to list or whatever you want here
```

outputs like this

```
-1
459
100
300
```

Comment: The code works, thank you very much! It is a very easy way to work indeed.

Comment: This is great! Just need to add the parenthesis around print(). I don't think that can be edited here.

Answer (score 14):

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    select = UI.Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="countries"]'))
    for option in select.options:
        print(option.text, option.get_attribute('value'))
```

prints

```
(u'--SELECT COUNTRY--', u'-1')
(u'New Zealand', u'459')
(u'USA', u'100')
(u'UK', u'300')
```

I learned this [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2258). See also [the docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html).

Comment: And it works! :) Yeah, I will read the docs a little more, I couldn't get the select to work properly when I have tried. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Simpler version:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 

dropdown_menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_name(<NAME>))
   
for option in dropdown_menu.options:
            print(option.text, option.get_attribute('value'))
```

Answer (score 1):

A little improved answer.
In Selenium and Python, if you want to get all attribute values, use following list comprehension:

```
options = [x.get_attribute("value") for x in driver.find_element_by_id("yourlocator").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
print(options)
```

Simple call to `.text` won't work for lists.
Use:

```
options = [x.get_attribute("innerText") for x in driver.find_element_by_id("yourlocator").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
print(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since selenuim methods like `find_elements_by_tag_name` are now descripted,
TehTris' answer (which is great) might need a little update.

Firstly, we make sure we **also** import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Then we set our driver (aka browser) and go to the desired url:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("desired_url.com")
```

Now we create the select_box like this:

```
select_box = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="countries"]'))
```

And now we can extract the values by iterating over `select_box.options`

```
[i.get_attribute('value') for i in select_box.options]
```