# Unable to print text of options in select in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, html-select

I try to print out text of all options in select element. But the result is just null string despite the len of that list is true.
I have read some other similar questions but no soltion works for me.
here are some of my attempts:
Attempt 1:

```
select = UI.Select(browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Xuất xứ']"))
#select = Select(browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Xuất xứ']"))
options = select.options
print(len(options))
for item in options:
    print(item.text, item.get_attribute('value'))
```

Result:

```
17

 ko972
 ko973
 ko974
 ko975
 ko976
 ko977
 ko978
 ko979
 ko980
 ko981
 ko982
 ko983
 ko984
 ko985
 ko986
 ko987
```

--> It means that the xpath is true and I can reach the value attribute of those options. 17 is the len of options. But item.text returns null
Here is the html of that select element:

```html
<select class="form-control  selectized" data-bind="selectize:SelectedAtt, selectizeOptions:AttributeValues, optionsText: 'Value', value: SelectedAtt, enable: $parent.ProductDetail().CanEdit, optionsCaption: 'Vui lòng chọn'
                                 , attr: {id: $data.Name() }
                                " tabindex="-1" id="Xuất xứ" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Vui lòng chọn</option>
<option value="ko947">Hàn Quốc</option>
<option value="ko948">Mỹ</option>
<option value="ko949">Anh</option>
<option value="ko950">Pháp</option>
<option value="ko951">Thụy Sỹ</option>
<option value="ko952">Nga</option>
<option value="ko953">Na Uy</option>
<option value="ko954">Nhật</option>
<option value="ko955">Đài Loan</option>
<option value="ko956">Trung Quốc</option>
<option value="ko957">indonesia</option>
<option value="ko958">Singapore</option>
<option value="ko959">Malaysia</option>
<option value="ko960">Khác</option>
<option value="ko961">Việt nam</option>
<option value="ko962">Việt Nam</option>
</select>
```

attempt 2:

```
options=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='Xuất xứ']/option")
print(len(options))
for item in options:
     print(item.text)
```

The result is the same that it returns the true len of options but each item in that list is null.
Result of attempt 2:

```
17
```

Pls, share me solution for this problem. I want to get text of those options.
thanks alot

Some of my readings:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver/2258#2258

[Listing select option values with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515692/listing-select-option-values-with-selenium-and-python/18516161)

[How to print the text of the selected option choosen through 'selectByVisibleText' method in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903657/how-to-print-the-text-of-the-selected-option-choosen-through-selectbyvisibletex)

Comment: can you share the result(print) of the second attempt?

Comment: Yes, it's added. I also edit my typo mistake in attempt 2 code (change get_elements_by_xpath to find_elements_by_xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`innerText` property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)

```
for item in select.options:
    print(item.get_attribute('innerText'), item.get_attribute('value'))
```

It might be also beneficial if you consider [Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) design pattern, it will allow you to split test logic from DOM and the process of tests development and especially support/fixing will be faster and easier.

More information: [Page Objects](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html)

Comment: It's awesome! That works exactly as my expectation. Thank you so much for this result and for the POM suggustion to read. Thanks!!!!

Comment: if possible, pls take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625545/csv-selenium-and-loop-can-not-go-together-wrong-looping-result-after-running-s

Answer (score 0):

To print the text value of options.Use the property value `innerHTML`

```
options=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='Xuất xứ']/option")
print(len(options))
for item in options:
     print(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

### Output:

```
17
Vui lòng chọn
Hàn Quốc
Mỹ
Anh
Pháp
Thụy Sỹ
Nga
Na Uy
Nhật
Đài Loan
Trung Quốc
indonesia
Singapore
Malaysia
Khác
Việt nam
Việt Nam
```