# Can't access iframe in python selenium, receive stale error

Tags: python, selenium

I want to be able to scrape ticket information from [this website](https://www.alcatrazcruises.com/checkout/?id=1000016).  I currently am receiving a stale error issue when trying access elements after switching to iframe.  I want to be able to loop through the calendar days and be able to see available tickets for different days.

I have tried to access the iframe with different approaches like using `WebDriverWait().until(EC.frame_to_avaiable_and_switch_to_it()` and also tried to find the iframe element using `XPATH`, `CLASS_NAME` and `CSS_SELECTOR`.

```py
def get_available_dates(driver, delay=30):
    elm = (By.XPATH, '//iframe')
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(elm))

    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
    print len(iframes) #Sometimes this shows 0, 1, or 5


    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe) #sometimes throw error
    elm = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'CalendarMonth_table.CalendarMonth_table_1')
    calendar_table = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(elm)) #Throws Timeout Exception or iframe stale error

    rows = calendar_table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    print "row cnt: {}".format(len(rows))
    print rows
```

I added expected results and errors as comments

Comment: You should try to search keyword "innerHTML" since all subelements of <div class="jss172"> may be in type of innertext/innerHtml.

Comment: you may take a look some questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python . or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644605/unable-to-print-text-of-options-in-select-in-selenium-python