# Using Selenium to grab specific information in Python

Tags: python, selenium

So I am quite new to using Selenium and thus and quite unsure how to do this, or even word it for this matter.

But what I am trying to do is to use selenium to grab the following values and then store them into a list.

Image provided of the inspector window of Firefox, to show what I am trying to grab (Highlighted)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHk9R.png

Comment: Question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515692/listing-select-option-values-with-selenium-and-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Selenium, you access elements using functions `find_element(s)_by_xxx()`, where `xxx` is for example the tag name, element name or class name (and more). The functions `find_element_...` return the first element that matches the argument, while `find_elements_...` return all matching elements.

Selenium has a [good documentation][1], in section "Getting started" you can find several examples of basic usage.

As to your question, the following code should collect the values you want:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # driver for the browser you use

    select_elem = driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00_Content...')  # full name of the element
    options = select_elem.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')

    values = []

    for option in options:
      val = option.get_attribute('value')
      values.append(val)
```